# Replacing “index” array string using Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

with the following code can get the 1 in the string.

```
var match = /[0-9]+/.exec('[1][2]');
console.log(match);
```

How do i get the 2 and not the 1 ?

Comment: You need to use a while loop, see MDN for an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec  Note that if your goal is to perform a replacement, you don't need to use the exec method, use String.prototype.replace with the g parameter.

Comment: Use `var match = '[1][2]'.match(/[0-9]+/g).pop();`

Comment: the final code is ugly but it works. Thank you! `item.attr( { name: name.replace(name.match(/[0-9]+/g).pop(), clone.attr('data-ordem')) } );`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex

```
console.log(/(\[[0-9]\])+/.exec('[1][2]'));
```

I think it's only a matter of escaping the square brackets

Comment: You can't repeat a capture group because at each iteration, the previous capture is overwritten with the next.

Comment: Yes, but he asked to get the `2`, I assumed it as "get the latest one", the related answer (marked as duplicate) has a better answer anyway :)